# How to repopulate a Redis DB before each test in Mocha?

Tags: node.js, testing, redis, mocking, mocha.js

I am currently designing a test plan for the APIs of a node.js web app. We use mongo and redis DBs there, and I have created specific instances of them for running tests using that data.

My idea is to have both DB instances in a determined state before each test run. For that, I would erase both DB data and repopulate them again with the desired data. I would like Something like this:

```
describe("tests for API x", function() {
  beforeEach(function(done) {
    testUtils.deleteMongoData(...
    testUtils.deleteRedisData(...
    testUtils.insertMongoData(...
    testUtils.insertRedisData(...
      done();
      ...
    });
  });

  //Tests of the API x with DB data in the desired state
  ...
```

In the case of Mongo my idea is load the data from a JSON structure each time. But I am no sure what is the best option to insert data into redis before each test run. I am currently inserting manually before each test, but is not practical at all. I would like to do something similar to the JSON used for mongo.

I am currently trying the approach of loading the data using a .rbd suggested by @zenbeni.

Comment: How much data do you need to load?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @zenbeni.  I've actually never worked with them so maybe that could be the solution I was looking for. I will find info about it

Comment: @soveran, the amount of data is not huge, but is big enough to be impractical inserting manually before each test.

Comment: If it's a lot of data, you can use an rdb dump as @zenbeni suggested and restart Redis before running the tests. As an alternative, you could try pipelining all the commands needed to recreate the database.